# People around a table without neighbors of the same-colored shirt?

Tags: combinatorics

> $30$ people sit around a table. Half are wearing red and half are wearing blue. Is it always possible to find at least one person whose immediate neighbors have the same color shirt?

My attempt: Suppose not. Then we can't have more than two consecutive people with the same shirt color, and we also can't have a person with both neighbors wearing the opposite color from him, i.e we can't have less than two consecutive people with the same shirt color. Hence colors come in pairs, contradicting the fact there's an odd number of each.

Is this reasoning correct, or am I (as usual) way off?

Comment: Are we to assume that shirt color is a proxy for gender?

Comment: @lulu yes, sorry.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. Unusual things can happen too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is valid. Here is another way that proceeds by trying, then failing, to construct the "suppose not" case.

Number the seats 1 to 30 around the circle and consider the person in seat 2. No matter what colour is worn there, seats 1 and 3 must have opposite colours. Without loss of generality, let the person at seat 1 have a red shirt, and that at seat 3 a blue shirt:

```
1 2 3
R X B
```

Now consider the person at seat 4. Because seat 3 has a blue shirt, seat 5 must have a red shirt:

```
1 2 3 4 5
R X B X R
```

Indeed, we can continue around the table in this manner, with people in odd-numbered seats forced to wear alternately red and blue shirts:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 27 28 29
R X B X R X B ...  B  X  R
```

Seat 29 ends up red. But now consider seat 30, which is adjacent to seats 29 and 1, *both* of which have red shirts. We have arrived at a contradiction, so there must be at least one person whose neighbours wear shirts of the same colour.

Comment: What if we only ask for a person whose immediate neighbors both have red shirts?

Comment: @combinarcotics Still not possible. Runs of red are still limited to two, and the gaps between must be at least two. You can still string two reds and two blues, but still you must have some person between two red shirts. Same reasoning applies for the blues.

Comment: You mean it's still possible? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @combinarcotics I meant "still not possible to find a counterexample". There will always be a person with the given property.

Comment: Okay, and I didn't follow the explanation - where are we using the fact there's the same number of both?

Comment: The string has 14 reds and 12 blues, alternating RRBBRR...BBRR. The remaining space looks like ...RR????RR... and we must put one R and 3 Bs in there. No matter how we place them in the gap, we are bound to get one person between two reds.

Comment: I'm trying to explain to myself why this holds if we don't assume there is such a string but I don't know how..